# Request for member 'subview' in something not a structure or union?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created a gradient using Quartz, only one issue. I can't get it to rotate with the screen. I've tried everything listed on [this tutorial](http://www.danielbeard.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/gradient-background-for-uiview-in-ios/). Here's the view controller header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RadialGradientBackgroundViewController : UIViewController {

}

@end
```

And here's the view controller:

```
#import "RadialGradientBackgroundViewController.h"
#import "BackgroundLayer.h"

@implementation RadialGradientBackgroundViewController

/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer gradient];
    bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
}

-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [[[self.subview.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:self.view.bounds]; // Error is here!
}

/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Change `subview` to `view`.

Comment: @rmaddy That removes the error, but it doesn't allow for the gradient to change the direction.

Comment: But that wasn't your question, right? To the extent that you bothered to ask a question, it was: *Request for member 'subview' in something not a structure or union?*

Comment: @Caleb Sorry about that, I'm new to stackoverflow and I'm didn't understand how it worked at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view controller does not have a `subview` property or method. As [rmaddy said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250060/request-for-member-subview-in-something-not-a-structure-or-union#comment39339138_25250060), change `subview` to `view`.

Comment: Like I said to rmaddy, it removes all errors and I can build, yet when I rotate the iPhone, it doesn't change the gradient. I should note I am using xCode 3.2 with the iOS simulator running an iPhone on 4.3.

Comment: @jak1200 as Caleb pointed out, the `subview` → `view` change fixes the issue as stated. If you now have a different problem, please open a different question with a title that describes what is going on.

Comment: @ZevEisenburg Alrighty, will do. Thanks again for the help. :)